# I read 3 expressions seperated by colon(;) is required in for loop in c programming , but this question testing expression is ommited ,is it possible?

Tags: c, loops

In the following code testing expression is not given according to my knowledge, but as I read it is necessary to have initialisation, testing and increment function in for() part, how is it possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   
    int i=1,j=1;
    for(;; i+=j)
    {
        if(i>5)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            j+=i;
        }
        printf("\n%d",j);
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no problems: `i` and `j` are initialized upon declaration and `break` terminates the loop. This code is just ugly.

Comment: You don't have to have any. `for(;;)` is also fine, and is sometimes used for a loop that never ends.

Answer (score 1):

Because omitting the parts is allowed by the specification. Omitted loop condition implies an infinite loop.

[N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) says:

> 6.8.5.3 The for statement
> 1
> The statement
>
> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is
> evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
> The expression expression-3 is
> evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a
> declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and
> the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution
> before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
> evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.158)
> 2
> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a
> nonzero constant.